# Check if Popped UIViewController gets dismissed by swipe

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, navigationcontroller

I want to check whenever the user swipes a popped viewController away. So for example when in whatsApp a user exits the current chat by swiping from the edge. How is that possible in Swift?

I don't want to use viewDidDisappear, because this method also gets called when another viewController is presented over the current viewController.

Comment: Maybe you can just check if in `viewDidDisappear` the `navigationController` is nil; this can be a solution but not sure how much can fit your scenario

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly. If you want you can add this comment as a question and I´ll mark it as correct.

Comment: Thank you, I put it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in comment, a simple workaround would be in `viewDidDisappear`, check if the `navigationController` is `nil`.

```swift
class MyVc: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        if navigationController == nil {
            print("view controller has been popped")
        }
    }

}
```

**Of course, this solution works only if the view controller is embedded into a navigation controller, otherwise the if statement will always be `true`.**

Comment: This will not work when there are multiple `UIViewController`s on the stack - right? Only if it was the *last* VC that you swiped away.

Answer (score 4):

This "swipe" is handled by the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` of the `UINavigationController`. It is possible to set the delegate of this gesture recognizer to your `UIViewController` as follows:

```swift
navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
```

Then, you can implement the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` in your `UIViewController`. This would look like this:

```swift
extension YourViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        guard gestureRecognizer.isEqual(self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer) else { return true }
        
        print("The interactive pop gesture recognizer is being called.")
        return true
    }
}
```

I haven't tested the code, but this should print every time the interactivePopGestureRecognizer is used.

For more information, refer to the documentation of the [interactivePopGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621847-interactivepopgesturerecognizer) and [UIGestureRecognizerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate).

Comment: This is such a useful thing to know. I was using the UINavigationBarDelegate to intercept popping, but it would crash if the code prevented the pop when the user swiped to pop. Intercepting the swipe here instead fixes this problem, and we can pop using code if the conditions are met. Thanks!